# Buy and Sell in same block number with 2 differents hash

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

Solved :

1. Creat a 1st function only for Buy and a 2nd function for Sell with 'balanceOf = amountOut' before swap in Solidity
2. Call in order from your JAVASCRIPT or Python etc ....

Comment: Did you try creating two transactions?

Comment: Ok you mean create two transaction in Javascript ?
const BuyTx ?
const SellTx ? 

Or in Solidity 1 function Buy and 1 function Sell ? make a bool (amount > 0) on sell ?
Can you explain me what you mean please Ismael ?

Comment: I don't understand your problem, but if you need two transaction hashes, then just create two transactions. Also unless you use something like flashbots there's no way to ensure two transactions will be in the same block.

Comment: Its ok i'm sorry i'm newbie in solidity and alone to learn .. ^^ Thank you